# How are ElasticSearch Autogenerated IDs allocated?

Tags: elasticsearch

The [ElasticSearch docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/docs-index_.html#_automatic_id_generation) say "The index operation can be executed without specifying the id. In such a case, an id will be generated automatically." Is there any information about how these are generated, and specifically how they're kept unique? Are they monotone increasing in a string comparison over time? Are they allocated as per-node ranges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always, the best source of information is the source code itself.

In [`IndexRequest.java`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/14b5308983c99c0b716e77ba9363841d63d8d0c0/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/index/IndexRequest.java#L617), we can see that if no ID is provided, the one that is automatically generated is a Base64 encoded time-based UUID ([source](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/14b5308983c99c0b716e77ba9363841d63d8d0c0/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/common/Strings.java#L1068)) whose implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/14b5308983c99c0b716e77ba9363841d63d8d0c0/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/common/TimeBasedUUIDGenerator.java). They are essentially [Flake IDs](http://www.bmc.com/truesightpulse/blog/2012/01/flake-a-decentralized-k-ordered-unique-id-generator-in-erlang).